# Limiting the size of data being read from a CSV file so it reads only full lines

Tags: c#, csv, filestream

I want to use C# to read a CSV file of about 10GB. I can't read the file one line at a time and have a limitation of reading a maximum chunk of 32MB at a time.

How can I limit the size of the data I'm reading BUT also make sure I'm reading only full lines? That means that if a full 32MB means reading just for example 100.5 lines, then I want to read only the full 100 lines and leave out the half line even if it means reading less than 32MB.

This is the skeleton code I was thinking about (the comments there hold more questions):

```
const int MAX_BUFFER = 33554432; //32MB
        byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER];
        int bytesRead;
        using (System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, MAX_BUFFER)) != 0)
            {
                //should I somehow analyze here if what I'm reading containing only full lines? 
                //and if so, how can I know that I'm not currently reading something less than 32MB 
                //meaning bytesRead is less than that and that maybe I'm going to read the rest of the line in the next iteration?
            }
```

Comment: Would `File.EnumerateLines` solve your problem?

Comment: @usr What you wrote doesn't seems to exist...

Comment: Seems to be called `ReadLines´. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx What about that?

Comment: @Steve but how can I know that what I'm reading at the end of the chunk is not a full line? It seems like you assume that I always read a piece of a line at the end of the chunk

Comment: @Yonatan - I've moved all my comments into an answer. If this works for you, accept it. You might want to wait for more input though.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to ensure you're reading full lines.

Read the file by chunks into a buffer.

Process each line from your buffer character by character, until you reach a newline character. If you're on a line and reach the end of the buffer, keep that portion around, read the next chunk, and concatenate everything from the new read up to a newline with the left overs from the previous read.

If the very last byte of the buffer is a new-line, you have a whole line and can simply move on the the next chunk. If not, read the next chunk - either the first byte will be a new-line, or you'll have other characters before it. Either way, concat everything up to the newline (even if that means 0 characters) and start on the next.

If you hit the end of file after a newline, you're done. If you hit the end of file while processing non-newline characters, it's up to you whether you want to keep them as a valid line or discard them.

This is very similar to a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Another solution might be to use a `BufferedStream` and specify the buffer size. Then just read byte by byte to each newline or EOF.

Comment: +1, this seems to be the way to go.  you might also want to ensure that you're only looking for newline characters *outside* of quoted strings that can be present in CSV files.

Comment: No, sorry, and I don't have the time to write one at the moment.